# Bootstrap mobile transitions

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a way to do page transitons with Bootstrap.
I have been using jQuery mobile which does allow page transitions but I have found a dislike to it and changed to Bootstrap.

So my question is:

Is there a way to do page transitions with jQuery mobile but with bootstrap?
or any sort of plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a bootstrap-specific equivalent to jQuery Mobile transitions also, but haven't found much.

This one is pretty simple and interesting though, if it helps: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kevinknelson/bootstrap-mobile

You should have a look at this,